# Grouping stream using criteria conditions without using forEach and two external lists

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a Trade Object, that has inQty, outQty and tradeType. 
TradeType can be 'Fixed' or 'Moveable'. The quantity fields are of type Double.

Using java 8 streams is it possible to split the stream into two groups as below

```
1.All Trades that are 'Fixed' + All trades that are 'Moveable' and
have both inQty and outQty greater than 0.0

2. All trades that are 'Moveable' and inQty and outQty are zero value
(0.0)
```

One approach that I am aware of is using forEach and add the objects to two different array lists of trades. 
**Is there any better approach to achieve this?**

```
List<Trade> storageAndNonZeroMoveableTrades= new ArrayList<>();
List<Trade> zeroMoveableTrades= new ArrayList<>();
trades.forEach( i -> {
            if(i.tradeType().equals(STORAGE_TRADE)){
                storageAndNonZeroMoveableTrades.add(i);
            }else if(i.tradeType().equals(MOVEABLE_TRADE)){
                    if(Double.compare(i.inQty(), 0.0d) != 0 &&
                        Double.compare(i.outQty(), 0.0d) != 0){
                            storageAndNonZeroMoveableTrades.add(i);
                }else{
                        zeroMoveableTrades.add(i);
                    }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) Collector.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Trade t1 = new Trade(0.0, 0.0, FIXED);
        Trade t2 = new Trade(1.1, 2.2, FIXED);
        Trade t3 = new Trade(0.0, 0.0, MOVEABLE);
        Trade t4 = new Trade(3.3, 4.4, MOVEABLE);
        Stream<Trade> trades = Stream.of(t1, t2, t3, t4);

        Map<String, List<Trade>> groups = trades.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Main::classify));
        System.out.println(groups);
    }

    static String classify(Trade to) {
        return (to.tradeType == MOVEABLE && to.inQty == 0 && to.outQty == 0)
                ? "zeroMoveableTrades" : "storageAndNonZeroMoveableTrades";
    }

    public static class Trade {
        public final double inQty;
        public final double outQty;
        public final TradeType tradeType;

        public Trade(double inQty, double outQty, TradeType tradeType) {
            this.inQty = inQty;
            this.outQty = outQty;
            this.tradeType = tradeType;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{inQty="+ inQty +", outQty="+ outQty +", tradeType="+ tradeType +"}";
        }
    }

    public enum TradeType {
        FIXED, MOVEABLE
    }
}
```

Comment: `partitonBy` makes more sense here.

Comment: `Trade` objects could be divided into any number of groups. I hesitate to implement a boolean split here simply because there happen to be two groups mentioned. Besides, it's not obvious which group should be `true` and which should be `false`.